How to get transactions from Coinbase API V3?
I'm trying to get transaction data for my account from Coinbase's API (eg: "bought X_AMOUNT of BTC with USDC").
I've tried the following endpoints:

/api/v3/brokerage/orders/historical/fills
/api/v3/brokerage/orders/historical/batch

but both return empty data even though I can see recent transactions in my account. All the posts I've seen related to this use the deprecated V2 API.
Is there a way to do this with the current API?

Can you include more information about what requests you've tried and responses you've received from them? Especially the query parameters of the requests, and the full body of the response, it's difficult to help you without more information about what you've tried.

@paammar I've tried /api/v3/brokerage/orders/historical/fills and /api/v3/brokerage/orders/historical/batch with no query parameters. "historical/batch" returns {"orders":[],"sequence":"0","has_next":false,"cursor":""}, "historical/fills" returns {"fills":[],"cursor":""}

You need to give more details on how you are generating the JWT token.  It requires a new token for each call and each endpoint.  Which language are you using? how are you making the call? postman? curl? node? php?

have you tried api/v3/brokerage/transaction_summary?

Make sure you have your API key, secret, and passphrase ready. Install the requests library if you haven't already:
pip install requests

Example API call:
import requests
import time
import hmac
import hashlib
import base64

# Replace these values with your actual API key, secret, and passphrase
api_key = 'your_api_key'
api_secret = 'your_api_secret'
api_passphrase = 'your_api_passphrase'

# Get the current timestamp in seconds
timestamp = str(int(time.time()))
method = 'GET'
request_path = '/api/v3/brokerage/orders/historical/fills'

# Create the prehash string by concatenating the timestamp, method, and request path
message = timestamp + method + request_path
hmac_key = base64.b64decode(api_secret)
signature = hmac.new(hmac_key, message.encode('utf-8'), hashlib.sha256).digest()
signature_b64 = base64.b64encode(signature).decode('utf-8')

headers = {
    'CB-ACCESS-KEY': api_key,
    'CB-ACCESS-SIGN': signature_b64,
    'CB-ACCESS-TIMESTAMP': timestamp,
    'CB-ACCESS-PASSPHRASE': api_passphrase,
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}

url = 'https://api.coinbase.com' + request_path

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
data = response.json()

print(data)

Assuming there are transactions in your account, the response might look like this:
{
  "fills": [
    {
      "order_id": "12345",
      "trade_id": "67890",
      "product_id": "BTC-USDC",
      "price": "30000.00",
      "size": "0.01",
      "fee": "0.0001",
      "side": "buy",
      "created_at": "2023-07-01T10:00:00Z",
      "liquidity": "T",
      "settled": true
    },
    {
      "order_id": "23456",
      "trade_id": "78901",
      "product_id": "ETH-USDC",
      "price": "2000.00",
      "size": "0.5",
      "fee": "0.01",
      "side": "sell",
      "created_at": "2023-07-02T11:00:00Z",
      "liquidity": "M",
      "settled": true
    }
  ],
  "pagination": {
    "after": "cursor_after",
    "before": "cursor_before",
    "limit": 100
  }
}

Note:
Correct API key permissions: Make sure that the API key has the correct permissions to access trade data.
Date range and filters: Make sure the transactions you are querying fall within the date range and other filters (if any) applied in the request.
Verify transactions exist: Confirm that there are indeed transactions within the specified timeframe in your account.
Good luck!
